# Frame wall with steel post at corner

Tags: drywall, walls, framing

How do I frame this corner?  There are already two walls up (the one on the left that will become a closet), but that the corner where they meet is a steel post.  Obviously I can't move that, and I can't move the walls as they support the stairs.

For what it's worth, the distance from the pole to the edge on the right side is 15/16" (and that's being generous) and about 1 1/4" to the bottom.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the post inside the line of both walls?  How far?

Comment: are you planning on applying some type of sheetrock as a skin to this wall?

Comment: Was this question resolved? Was an acceptable solution accepted?

Answer (score 3):

if the post is within the line of the walls:

[image]

Blue is existing, red is nailing strips, green is bulkhead...

Comment: What is the yellow in the picture? FWIW, I only have 15/16" on the right and 1 1/4" on the bottom MAX.

Comment: Yellow is a batten to help tie the two greens together. You can use 3/4" planks for the green bulkhead, with a 1x1 batten inside the corner for extra strength.

Answer (score 1):

Build a wall in front of the short wall with the studs oriented flat.  Use a PT 2x2 for extending the sole plate. Block the end solid to the post with ripped studs as required to strengthen corner.

Blocking is lumber used for additional nailing surfaces and/or to create rigidity in the direction perpendicular to the primary framing members.

Solid blocking is blocking which fills a void.

Cost is an inch and a half of additional thickness.

Comment: Seems to make sense. I plan on putting a closet door in the short wall.  Will this cause any problems?  What about the drywalling the 1.5" on the (left side)?  Is that advised, or should I just rip down the drywall that's there now and just extend with a full new piece?  

"Block the end solid to the post with ripped studs as required to strengthen corner."  I assume by block the end solid you mean put the studs like an L in the corner. Can you clarify "as required to strengthen corner"?

Comment: @2LeftThumbs See definitions in my edit answer. Finishing the thicker wall might require some additional trim at the new door depending on the aesthetic objective.

Comment: So I was just looking at it and I'm wondering how I would add the blocking at the corner as the blocking would be directly under the steel beam?